# Setting up an Outlook email programmatically in Windows

Tags: .net, python, email, com

How would I go about this? What language would I need to use (Python preferred, as the rest of my installation script is in Python)? Something with access to the .NET libraries (VB.NET, C#, IronPython, maybe PyWin32) or COM? Or is there just some easy command-line trick?

I'm not against using a .NET library or COM object, but my knowledge of them is limited and I'm using standard Python (and don't know C# or VB, though I'm not against learning).

I'm talking about mostly Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010. The more generic the better, because it'll be used for users who will be assigned both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Outlook can be configured using profile files from the command line:

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc179062.aspx

Comment: Yes, but figuring out how to use profiles is absolutely, terribly difficult from what I've found! I've been looking into this solution since an hour or two after I posted that.

Comment: Any idea how to create a profile without OCT? I don't have this software.

Comment: Ah, beautiful. I am in about the same situation I was before, then.